# Magento2 site loads 404 page instead of homepage

Tags: magento2

Trying to troubleshoot what happened on a Magento 2.2.5 based website. We all of a sudden noticed that when you go to our website it just loads a 404 page even though the home page is set in the configuration admin screen and the CMS page does exist. When I look at the exception.log when I try to go to the main page I get the below error?

```
Unable to read response, or response is empty {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Http_Client_Exception(code: 0): Unable to read response, or response is empty at vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/Client.php:1093)"} []
```

If I go directly to the url of the homepage cms page the page loads fine.